# successively calling temporary object's methods

Tags: c++

Is following code standard compliant:

```
struct Temp
{
    Temp& op1() { ...; return *this; }
    Temp& op2() { ...; return *this; }
    // more op...
};

Temp().op1().op2()....;   // safe or not? Which paragraph from ISO 12.2 qualifies it?
```

Comment: I think it is safe. The life time of the temporary object is until the semicolon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Totally safe.

It's in paragraph 3 (of §12.2, `[class.temporary]`):

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

§1.9/10 (`[intro.execution]`) defines full-expression:

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.

and includes an example somewhat similar to your question:

```
void f() {
  if (S(3).v()) // full-expression includes lvalue-to-rvalue and
                // int to bool conversions, performed before
                // temporary is deleted at end of full-expression
  { }
}
```

The quotes and paragraph numbering come from N3691, the mid-2013 c++-draft, but they haven't changed in a few years and they will probably continue to be valid in C++1x and quite possibly even in C++1y (x≅4; y≅7)

Comment: Presumably the standard references refer to C++11? Note that which standard is current, can have changed when some googler stumbles on this answer.

Comment: Yes, C++11. It's a bit late here, but I'll fix it before the current standard is replaced or tomorrow, whichever comes first.

Comment: In 2014, that's next year. Hopefully.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Except in standards-land, 2014 is this year :) Still, it is possible that we'll see C++14 by 2015. I don't remember seeing any proposals which would renumber the cited paragraphs, but I haven't studied it all in huge depth. Anyway, edited the answer; if you have a more specific suggestion about how to cite the standard in the light of possible future changes, I'm all ears.

Comment: +1 for the will to do properly. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Original code:

```
struct Temp
{
    Temp& op1() { ...; return *this; }
    Temp& op2() { ...; return *this; }
    // more op...
}
```

Due to the lack of a final semicolon this code is not standard-compliant and will not compile.

It illustrates the importance of posting real code.

---

That said, yes, member functions, even non-`const` member funcitons, can be called on temporary class type objects, and that includes the assignment operator.

And yes, the lifetime of a temporary extends to the end of the full expression (unless extended by binding to a reference).

Comment: Also the ellipsis inside function body will not compile.